# How can I solve this : Cannot Get /upload error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cloaned this code on youtube, it has Cannot GET /upload error.

I search google about this error, and many say it looks like app.get('/upload') missing problem.

But I don't know how to fix this code.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const fs = require('fs');

const ipfs = new ipfsClient(
  {host:'localhost',
  port:'5001',
  protocol:'http'
});
const app = express();
app.engine('ejs',require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(fileupload());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('home');
});

**app.post('/upload', (req,res)=>{
  const file = req.files.file;
  const fileName = req.body.fileName;
  const filePath = 'files/' + fileName;
  
  file.mv(filePath, async(err) => {
    if (err){
      console.log('Error failed to download the file');
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    
    const fileHash = await addFile(fileName, filePath);
    fs.unlink(filePath, (err)=>{
      if(err) console.log(err);
    });
    res.send(fileHash);
  });
});**


*const addFile = async(fileName, filePath) =>{
  const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const fileAdded = await ipfs.add({path:fileName,content:file});
  const fileHash = fileAdded[0].hash;
  return fileHash;
};*
```

Comment: How are you testing this code?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `/upload` route is specified for `POST` method:

```
app.post('/upload', (req,res)=>{
```

there is no `GET /upload` route, which is the error you're getting.

So when calling your endpoint, you should change the method to `POST`